# Possible to populate an array of structs after declaration?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm fairly new to C and was wondering if I could first initialize an array of structs of a set size, and then populate the array with the actual structs after declaration. The snippet of code below presents want I want to do, it should be pretty straightforward.

```
/* Make rectangle 2D object */
struct two_d_obj rect = {0, 4, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, -20.0}, {{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0, 0.1}, {0.1, 0}}};
struct two_d_obj obj_array[25];
obj_array[0] = rect;
```

However, when trying to compile this code, I get the following errors:

```
hellomousept2.c:39: error: conflicting types for ‘obj_array’
hellomousept2.c:33: error: previous definition of ‘obj_array’ was here
hellomousept2.c:39: error: invalid initializer
```

Again, I'm a newbie with C and primarily code in Java, so any help to get me on the right track would be highly appreciated and thanks is given in advance.

EDIT: below is the code for my two_d_obj struct

```
struct two_d_obj
{
    int iType; /*integer signifying shape of object (0 for rect, 1 for circle) */
    int num_vertices; /* number of vertices contained in the shape */
    double color[3]; /*array containing RGB values signifying color of object */
    double center_pos[2]; /*center position of object */
    double velocity[2]; /*velocity of object */
    double vertex_array[50][2]; /*array of vertice coordinates (read in pairs
                             x coordinate followed by y coordinate)
                             protocol: first pair of coordinates is bottom left
                             vertice, pairs that follow are vertices going
                             counter-clockwise       
                             */
};
```

Comment: Which is your definition of `two_d_obj`?

Comment: Seems like you have declared 'obj_array' twice. Once on line 33 and again on line 39. That's what the compiler message is trying to tell you.

Comment: @Kevin Lu the problem isn't in the code you gave, add struct declaration.

Comment: sorry. this is my first time posting and am having trouble formatting the code correctly to show up in my post. I tried pasting the code, and it didn't like my formatting, and yet, I cannot seem to indent using a tab since it will just move the cursor to the next window. Any tips?

Comment: Yes, insert the code and select it and then press the corresponding icon on the bar on top. Also, please provide all relevant code; as other said, the error is not in what you provided.

Comment: Select code and use braces{} icon.

Comment: Post line 33 and line 39 exactly as they are in your real code!  *Whenever you post an error, post the line it refers to* -- how else could anyone else say what's wrong?  This is as true for C as it is for java, etc. etc.

Comment: @goldilocks lines 33 and 39 are the array declaration and the assignment of rect to obj_array[0] respectively

Comment: So you propably got them wrong, still, post here

Comment: Ditto, triple check that Kevin.  Are you sure 39 isn't `struct obj_array[0] = rect;`?

Comment: @goldilocks out of curiosity, what would that actually mean?

Comment: @zubergu :  It or something like that might amount to a redefinition I guess, depending on the compiler -- although `gcc` calls it a straight syntax error ("expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token").  It has to be something like this, but of course without a "minimal reproducible example", who knows...

Comment: @goldilocks no, 39 is obj_array[0] = rect; should struct come before it?

Comment: No. The easiest way to get help with this kind of thing coincides with the easiest way to solve it yourself - try and write as minimal a program as you can reproducing the problem, so others can compile and test it. 85%+ of the questions I intend to ask never get posted because of that (in writing a *minimal reproducible example*, I find my mistake). By "minimal" I mean, (eg) if your example works to reproduce the issue with `struct two_d_obj` as is, simplify the struct until the issue doesn't reproduce. Likely the exact definition is irrelevant here and hence the struct could be very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is a struct, you can always do a memcpy

```
struct two_d_obj rect = { ... };
struct two_d_obj obj_array[25];
memcpy(obj_array,&rect,sizeof(two_d_obj ));
```

if you want to initialize more array members just loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
  memcpy(obj_array + i,&rect,sizeof(rect));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Structs can be passed as arguments to functions, can be returned by functions and can be both L-and R-value to operators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare an array and then populate it.  Simple example using a simple type:

```
char str[12];
char str[0] = 'a';
```

It is also possible to copy the value of compound types via assignment (=):

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct foo A = {
    .x = 1,
    .y = 2
};

struct foo B = A;
```

A and B will now be two separate structs with the same values.  With an array:

```
struct foo fooray[10];
fooray[0] = A;
```

You can also do this with initialization:

```
struct foo fooray[10] = { A };
```

Meaning, the first element of `fooray` will equal the pre-defined struct foo A.  If you *initialize* an array this way (partially), the remaining elements of the array will be zero'd out, hence:

```
struct foo fooray[10] = { { 0, 0 } };
// or more simply:
struct foo fooray[10] = { 0 };
```

Will be an array with all zero'd elements.   Note that most modern OS's will zero stack memory anyway for security reasons, but that is not part of the C standard, whereas using initialization is.

Answer (score 0):

Using a C99 (or later) 'compound literal' allows you to write:

```
struct two_d_obj obj_array[25];
obj_array[0] = (struct two_d_obj){ 0, 4, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, -20.0},
                                   { {0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0, 0.1}, {0.1, 0} } };
```

Syntactically, a compound literal consists of a cast specifying the type and a braced initializer with an initial value appropriate for the type specified in the cast.  It can be used wherever a value of the same type is required.

However, your immediate problem is that just before (or perhaps just after) the code in the question, you have also defined `obj_array`, and you can't define the same name twice in the same scope.

The third line of compiler message is inscrutable.  You will learn that the first error at a given line is usually accurate; second and subsequent error messages from the same line (or lines just after the first line with an error) are often just an indication that the compiler got confused because of the first problem and misinterpreted the rest of the line as a result.  I suspect the 'invalid initializer' warning fits into that category.  We can't be sure because you've not shown both lines 33 and 39 in your code.